# Interface Builder for iPhone tutorial

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

Anyone know of some tutorial material for how to use Interface Builder for iPhone development? I can find sample projects and stuff and that's extremely helpful, but they do not reveal how things where setup in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. All (at the time of this writing) are very helpful. For some reason the system doesn't allow me to check them all as valid answers. And my rep isn't high enough yet for me to vote up any answers. But anyway, I'm watching the casts and have bought that book. Great stuff!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pragmatic Programmers book [iPhone SDK Development](http://pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development) includes some Interface Builder walkthroughs.

Answer (score 5):

The Pragmatic Programmers have some [screencasts](http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-bdiphone/writing-your-first-iphone-application) on building an iphone application.  I haven't watched those, but I have watched some of their other videos and they were pretty good.

They've also got a free getting started with Xcode and Interface Builder episode, which may be what your looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually get a lot out of these screen-casts which are free as of now:
http://www.cocoacast.com/?q=blog/1

Note that they are very 'connected' to the Aaron Hillegass book on Mac programming (which is also a great resource). Some of them show him using IB (but of course not all). The book is more focused on Mac then iPhone, but if you're just trying to get going it's a great point of departure. I'm working on my first iPhone project and had never programmed with Objective C, XCode IDE and Interface Builder. I read the first 200 pages and used Apple's docs after that. Now it's been several months and I found the above screen-cast and wished I had that getting started! Good luck